# How to get Facebook Insights data of photo feed using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Insights API works properly for link feed but it doesn't work for photo feed. For photo feed, Insights API returns 0 or empty even though Insights page shows a high reach and engagement rate.

Here is the url pattern of my photo feed:

https://www.facebook.com/[PAGE]/photos/a.xxx.xxx.[PAGE ID]/[POST ID]/

Insights API returns:

```
{
    "id": "[PAGE ID]_[POST ID]/insights/post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique/lifetime", 
    "name": "post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique", 
    "period": "lifetime", 
    "values": [
        {
            "value": [
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "title": "Lifetime Talking About This (Post) by action type", 
    "description": "Lifetime: The number of unique people who created a story about your Page post by interacting with it. (Unique Users)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggeling with the same questions... one thing I can tell you is, that you most likely used a wrong id for you photo post.

Please ensure that you ONLY use ID's retrieved by a facebook api. So this is a sample process:

```
1. Note your page-id
2. Use GRAPH to query <url-to-graph>/<page_id>/feed?access_token=<your_token>
3. From the response, take the photo-post-id you want to analyze
4. Use GRAPH to query <url-to-graph>/<id_from_step_3>/insights/?access_token=<your_token>
5. Check the metrics returned from step 4 and enjoy!
```

Please keep in mind that there's an undocumented need to add your page_id to any post_id. So every replacement of {post-id} as it is written in the FB api's will be _.

Hope that helps...